# Pre-select Content in DisplayPromptAsync to allow overwriting easily

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Currently in my Xamarin Forms app I am using a `DisplayPrompt` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.displaypromptasync?view=xamarin-forms) to ask the user the Quantity they want for a specific Product / Item using the code below:

```
var quantity = await Shell.Current.DisplayPromptAsync("Quantity",
    "How many?",
    initialValue: "1",
    maxLength: 2,
    keyboard: Keyboard.Numeric,
    accept: "OK",
    cancel: "Cancel");
```

I was wondering if there was any way to `pre-select` the `initialValue` inside of the Prompt so that the user can just press a value on the Keyboard to overwrite it, similar to if you was to call: `SelectAll` method in C# (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectall?view=windowsdesktop-5.0)

I have done some research to see if I could create a Custom Control and this guide seems to be the closest possible solution https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2017/07/26/an-await-able-transparent-custom-popup-input-dialog-in-xamarin-forms/, but I didn't want to add extra complexity or change the UI/UX for the dialogs just for this seemingly small bit of functionality.

The only other solution I could think of is to set the `placeHolder` value to be 1 and remove the `initialValue` and then just check that the returned value is empty and not `null` which means the user clicked `OK` so they are meaning to set it as `1` but I think this may be confusing to some of our Users who are not very "tech savvy".

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you explain the specific error?

Comment: @WenxuLi-MSFT there isn't an `error` per-se, as I said in the question, I was wondering if there was a way to pre-select the content that is in the Entry for the `initialValue`, like the custom control link I put in the question, essentially I was just asking for potential solutions to achieving the simple functionality of preselecting the text in the DisplayPrompt

Comment: I need this as well. Example: User needs to enter number of copies of a print. Most often this is 1, so that is set as initial value. If user presses "2" to print two copies, it now says "12". If as requested, we could indicate the initial value should be preselected (quite a normal UI functionality), then when user presses "2", it would overwrite "1" and instead the value entered would be "2".

Comment: I've added a feature request to the new MAUI* repo in GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4981    *Multi-platform App UI - new name for Xamarin Forms merged with other libraries as well. Please go and subscribe and show your interest :-)